# Send string to input in a bash script while the previous command is awaiting input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdin

Yeah, that's a bad title, I know. I have no idea how to put this in words.

So I'm running linux and am setting up an openVPN; It's a hassle so I decided to make a BASH script that will do it for me. Here's what I have.

```
#!/bin/bash
PROMPT_COMMAND=
echo -en "\033]0;VPNBook\a"
cd ~/Other/VPN\'s/VPNBook
if ! pgrep openvpn > /dev/null
    then
    echo "VPN is not running"
    read -r -p "Would you like to start the VPN? [Y/n]" response
    response=${response,,}
    if [[ $response =~ ^(no|n)$ ]]
        then
        exit
    else
        echo "Starting VPN"
        # echo "Username: vpnbook"
        # echo "Password: 2Unuhust"
        # sudo echo

        # Line in question
        sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn
    fi
else
    echo "VPN is running"
    read -r -p "Would you like to stop the VPN? [Y/n]" response
    response=${response,,}
    if [[ $response =~ ^(no|n)$ ]]
        then
        exit
    else
        echo "Stopping VPN"
        sudo kill $(pidof openvpn)
    fi
fi
```

Sample output:

```
Wed Mar  2 23:06:52 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Enter Auth Username:vpnbook
Enter Auth Password:
```

So instead of entering the username and password manually I would like the script to enter them automatically as well as push enter.
So essentially once I have entered my password for sudo the script should do the rest.

I have done some googling and from what I understand most things don't work either because the command is not receiving the info as arguments or because the input is not going through STDIN because it's a password.

Thank you in advance and I'm sorry, I know it's not a great question.

Comment: Have you tried something simple like `sudo echo -e "vpnbook\n2Unuhust\n" | openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn`? This will pipe your username and password to openvpn for reading on stdin.

Comment: @JonathanEllithorpe No luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I solved it using expect. Here is my final code:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROMPT_COMMAND=
echo -en "\033]0;VPNBook\a"
cd ~/Other/VPN\'s/VPNBook
if ! pgrep openvpn > /dev/null
    then
    echo "VPN is not running"
    read -r -p "Would you like to start the VPN? [Y/n]" response
    response=${response,,}
     if [[ $response =~ ^(no|n)$ ]]
         then
         echo "Doing nothing"
    sleep 1
    exit
else
    echo "Starting VPN" 
    sudo ./startVPN.exp
fi
else
    echo "VPN is running"
    read -r -p "Would you like to stop the VPN? [y/N]" response
    response=${response,,}
    if [[ $response =~ ^(yes|y)$ ]]
        then
        echo "Stopping VPN"
        sudo kill $(pidof openvpn)
        echo "VPN Stopped"
            sleep 1
            exit
        else
            echo "Doing nothing"
            sleep 1
            exit
    fi
fi
```

And startVPN.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set PASS "2Unuhust"
set USER "vpnbook"
spawn openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn
expect "Enter Auth Username:"
send "$USER\r"
expect "Enter Auth Password:"
send "$PASS\r"
```